# Java - How to use functions in a stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

Recently, as part of my studies, we started practicing Java problem solving with streams.
While solving quantitative problems of add / subtract or string / character sorting problems with streams, relatively clear and understandable, however, a little more complicated problems are not clear to me with the use of streams.

For example, given a set of characters, we must print for each letter within the range G-O / g-o the inverse signal, such as A becomes Z, and the letter b becomes y.

For example, suppose we had the collection 'A','k','p' - > After the operation we will only get p.

Using simple functions, I was able to solve the problem as follows:

```
public static char flipLetter(char c){
    int count = 7;
    if((int)c >= 72 && (int)c <= 78){
        for (int i = 72; i <= 78; i++) {
            if((int)c == i)
                return (char)((int)'Z' - count);
            count++;
        }
    }
    else{
        for (int i = 104; i <= 110; i++) {
            if((int)c == i)
                return (char)((int)'z' - count);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
public static boolean isInRange(char c){
    return (((int)c >= 72 && (int)c <= 78) || ((int)c >= 104 && (int)c <= 110));

}
public static void inRange(char arr[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(isInRange(arr[i])){
            System.out.print(flipLetter(arr[i])+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

I'd be happy to get help on how I can use the code I wrote to implement it with streams, or hear other reviews.

Comment: Use `filter` and `map`, and then collect the stream using `Collectors.joining(" ")` to get the final string.

Comment: When you say "we must print for each letter within the range G-O / g-o" do you mean "we must print for each letter *NOT* within the range G-O / g-o"?

Comment: @Ray Toal I mean thatif the letter isn't at the range metion above we won't print it at all.

Comment: Do you want just the `inRange()` method using a stream, or all methods?

Comment: @Samuel Philipp if it can be done with only one the functions above, it would be great

Comment: *FYI:* Your `flipLetter` method is overly complicated, it can be simplified to `if (c >= 'H' && c <= 'N') { return (char)('Z' - (c - 'A')); } if (c >= 'h' && c <= 'n') { return (char)('z' - (c - 'a')); } return c;`

Comment: You're right, thanks for the comment.
Now you can improve the entire code into one function:  public static void inRange(char arr[]){
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if(arr[i] >= 'H' && arr[i] <= 'N'){
    System.out.print((char)('Z' - (arr[i] - 'A'))+" ");
   }
   else if((arr[i] >= 'h' && arr[i] <= 'n')){
    System.out.print((char)('z' - (arr[i] - 'a'))+" ");
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Why do you clutter your code with all these obsolete `(int)` type casts? Why don’t you write readable `'H'`, `'N'`, `'h'`, and `'n'` constants instead of `72`, `78`, `104`, and `110`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to write code documenting the intent to the reader. So when the task includes the condition “for each letter within the range G-O / g-o”, don’t write code like

```
public static boolean isInRange(char c) {
    return (((int)c >= 72 && (int)c <= 78) || ((int)c >= 104 && (int)c <= 110));
}
```

Write

```
public static boolean isInRange(char c) {
    return c > 'G' && c < 'O' || c > 'g' && c < 'o';
}
```

which makes it immediately obvious that you’re talking about the range “G-O / g-o (exclusive)” rather than “H-N/h-n (inclusive)”, not to speak about the unnecessary use of unicode/ascii numbers instead of writing char constants. The code will still do the same, but now, you can recognize the original task in it. The type casts are unnecessary in either variant.

As hinted by Andreas in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119947/java-how-to-use-functions-in-a-stream#comment98873390_56119947), you don’t need a counting loop for finding a difference, that’s what minus is for. So `flipLetter` simplifies to

```
    if(c > 'G' && c < 'O') {
        return (char)('Z' - (c - 'A'));
    }
    if(c > 'G' && c < 'O') {
        return (char)('z' - (c - 'a'));
    }
```

but when we use this after the range has been checked already, we can express the intent of differentiating between upper case and lower case directly, using `Character.isUpperCase(…)` or `Character.isLowerCase(…)`.

Further, basic arithmetic rules tell us that `'Z' - (c - 'A')` is the same as `('Z' + 'A') - c`, likewise for the lower case variant, so the code for the two cases only differs in a single constant value.

Putting these findings into a Stream operation yields

```
public static void yourTask(char[] arr) {
    CharBuffer.wrap(arr).chars()
        .filter(c -> c >= 'H' && c <= 'N' || c >= 'h' && c <= 'n')
        .map(c -> (Character.isUpperCase(c)? 'A'+'Z': 'a'+'z') - c)
        .forEachOrdered(ch -> System.out.print((char)ch+" "));
}
```

(A method name like `inRange` sounds like a test, so you should come up with a better name describing what the method actually does)

Note that this uses `IntStream`, as there is no `CharStream` in Java, which is fine as in Java, calculations involving `char` values are done using `int` anyway. Only at the final printing statement, we need to perform a type cast to `char`, to establish the right semantic, which affects the way, the value is printed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
public static void inRange(char arr[]){
    IntStream.range(0, arr.length).mapToObj(i -> arr[i])
             .filter(letter -> isInRange(letter))
             .map(letter -> flipLetter(letter))
             .forEach(e -> System.out.print(e  + " "));
}
```

Which will create a `Stream` of the `Array` passed, filter out any that are not in range, call the `flipLetter` method on each letter, and then print each out

Answer (score 0):

One solution for the `inRange()` method would be this:

```
public static void inRange(char[] arr) {
    IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> arr[i])
            .filter(YourClass::isInRange)
            .map(YourClass::flipLetter)
            .forEach(c -> System.out.print(c + " "));
}
```

If you want the result as `String` you can use this:

```
public static void inRange(char[] arr) {
    String result = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> arr[i])
            .filter(YourClass::isInRange)
            .map(YourClass::flipLetter)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

If you have a `String` as input, where you get the `char[]` from just pass that to the method ans use `string.chars()` instead of `IntStream.range(0, arr.length)`.